# issue in order controls in excel userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have issue in order controls in excel user form . I need to make the frame above the listbox . Am using the code :

```
With Frame7
.Visible = True
.ZOrder msoBringToFront
End With
```

Comment: Can I get you to redescribe the problem at hand?  You should be able to do .ZOrder msoSendBackward on the ListBox, but I may need more info.

Comment: fmtop and fmbottom, according to microsoft help

Comment: this worked for me. Worked great ona form

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the msoBringToFront is an integer, but the code below works sets the frame in front of every item

```
With Frame7
    .Visible = True
    .ZOrder (0)
End With
```