# Excel 2007: Modelsss UserForm Z-Order

Tags: excel, userform, z-order, vba

I am creating a series of Excel 2007 modeless userforms that I'd like to .Show and .Hide as needed.  The issue I'm trying to understand is how to change their z-order programmatically using VBA.  Does anyone have any suggestions or can you point me to a solution?

Thanks -

Comment: This might be of help to you: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=92064

Comment: Thanks, Ralph, for the response.  That article is about changing the z-order of controls located on userforms.  I need to manipulate the z-order of userforms themselves, not their controls.

Comment: my form was also modeless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I ultimately wound up using the Windows API to manage VBA userform Z-order.  Specifically, the SetWindowPos API function handles window Z-order with its hWndInsertAfter parameter.  I never found any native VBA methods or properties that could set userform Z-order (but I may have missed something).

Comment: I've been looking for the same type of method. I was hopeful when I found the information in the following stack overflow page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352422/issue-in-order-controls-in-excel-userform), but this did not seem to work.

Comment: Just as an update. The solution on the above stack overflow page did actually work for me. However, for some reason, i could only get it to work if i used the 'With'/'End With'. I could not just say txtBx.ZOrder msoSendToBack. At least I could not figure out a way to made it work without using the 'With' format.

Comment: @Fractal, if I remember correctly, my solution works only with form windows, not individual controls on a form.  I seem to recall that this is the case because the SetWindowPos API function only deals with windows and doesn't apply to individual controls.  My workaround to the problem of changing the Z-order for individual form controls is to create multiple versions of each form and call the form windows as needed.

Comment: I didn't use the SetWindowPos API function. I ended up using the information from this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352422/issue-in-order-controls-in-excel-userform). Also look at (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213680(v=office.11).aspx). The msdn page will give you a list of all options which can be used with zorder. This worked great for a label control i wanted to push to the back. But i had to use the 'With/End With'. i can't have multiple lines on a comment so i'll put an example code in an answer block below

Comment: okay i just read the the sub-comment above. Didn't realize this was about z-order for the form window itself.